# Equivalence of formulations of Nakayama's Lemma.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have in my notes two formulations of Nakayama's Lemma.

Formulation 1: Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m.$ Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R-$module and $N$ a submodule of $M.$ Then $mM = M$ implies $M = 0.$

Formulation 2: If $M = N + mM$ then $N = M.$

I can't see why these two formulations of Nakayama's Lemma are equivalent. More specifically why 1 implies 2. Supposing Formulation 1 and having $M = N + mM$ gives us $M - N = mM.$ How do we apply 1 from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ring theory is a bit rusty, but I guess you can look at the quotient module $M/N$ over $R$. Because $M=N+mM$, you have $M/N=mM/N$, thus $M/N=0$ thus $M=N$.

Comment: Wow that is good. Thank you.